# Kill cmd prompt after process finishes executing?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a Sublime build system which runs your current python code in a new cmd.exe window. This works well, but the issue I've run into is that I would like the cmd window to exit after the python process terminates. Instead, right now I can kill the python process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but that doesn't kill the window as well.

I've tried looking online for suggestions on how to do this, but I am unable to come up with anything. Solutions I'm thinking of right now include trying to write a wrapper around the cmd window to handle input and then kill when necessary, or maybe trying to do something with PowerShell (don't know if that'll be better or worse).

Currently, from Sublime, the following script is executed on build:

```
{
    "selector": "source.python",
    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["python-terminal.bat", "$file"]
    }
}
```

Which calls this batch file (with the filename given as an input). Note that this batch file requires changing python.exe (for python 3) to python3.exe.

```
@echo off
start cmd /k python3 -i %1
```

Comment: In the batch file, `start` might not be needed; to quit `cmd` after `python3 -i %1` has finished execution, replace switch `/k` by `/c`;

Comment: If you don't need the console window then use `pythonw.exe`

Comment: In this case, `start` is needed since the bat file is being invoked directly from Sublime - otherwise the output would get piped to sublime's non-interactive console. That said, I did remove `cmd` (though it also worked with `cmd /c`. I did in fact rename python.exe to python3.exe, because I did not know about the py.exe launcher - since you've pointed that out, I've changed the script. I have it piped through a bat file so that in the event that additional processing is needed, it will be easy to add (this is how I've done it on linux and mac). Thanks! (will add as an answer).

Comment: Oh, and the window is needed for the interactive shell that's launched after the program finishes executing with `python -i`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments above, I was able to get the issue resolved. As explained above, quirks of Sublime require the `start` command, but the new bat file is below:

(Google revealed that you can do `cmd /?` to figure out the list of flags, I should've searched for that earlier).

```
@echo off
start py.exe -3 -i %1
exit
```

The following also worked:

```
@echo off
start cmd /c py.exe -3 -i %1
exit
```

Comment: `start` will wait and set `errorlevel` if you use the `/w` switch, e.g. `start /w py.exe -3 -i %1`. Then the batch file can return the exit code to Sublime via `exit /b %errorlevel%`.

Comment: FYI, what `start` does here is to pass the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to the Windows `CreateProcess` function. With this flag set the child process gets standard handles that reference a new console window (i.e. a new instance of conhost.exe) instead of inheriting the standard handles from the parent process. This way you break out of Sublime's piped standard I/O.